# What is the preset field in systemctl status?

Tags: systemd, systemctl

This is the output:

```
systemctl --user status syncthing                                                             ✔  11:12:37 
○ syncthing.service - Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/syncthing.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:syncthing(1)
```

What is `preset: enabled` really telling me? Syncthing must be run as a user service, so maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: It just says that when installed it was enabled, and it has been disabled later on. As for this apache server just after install `Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)`

Comment: OK, so it just tells me what the preset status is in regards to "enabled/disabled"? And I guess "preset" and "vendor preset" are synonyms?

Comment: `preset` is whether your distribution is configured to have it enabled by default.  With debain-based distributions, when you install a service, it is enabled automatically.  With Arch or Red Hat (been a while since I used those), services are/were not enabled unless the user took action to enable it.  So if you have `disabled; preset: enabled`, then it probably means the system admin took actions to disable that service.

Comment: Nice! Thanks, guys! @admstg, feel free to post the solution as an answer and I will check it.

Comment: Kind of. I was just thrown off by the fact that all my distros say "preset" and others say "vendor preset" and all the resources I found were talking about "vendor preset" instances.

Comment: I know, there were vendor presets, config presets etc... it's just `preset` in more [recent_releases.](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/c1e0dc9c882dfae7ba4bf49c50fd253ea199e7d9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments :
It just says that when installed it was enabled, and it has been disabled later on. As for this apache server just after install Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)